# What are the steps to plugin UDF function into Presto?

Tags: udf, presto

I followed [this](https://www.qubole.com/blog/product/plugging-in-presto-udfs/?nabe=5695374637924352:1) tutorial and leveraged [this](https://github.com/qubole/presto-udfs) github project and wrote a simple 'mysum' UDF function.

```
@ScalarFunction("mysum")
@Description("Returns summation of two numbers")
@SqlType(StandardTypes.BIGINT)
public static long sum(@SqlType(StandardTypes.BIGINT) long num1, @SqlType(StandardTypes.BIGINT) long num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

I followed the below steps to plugin the UDF but Presto fails to import the function. *Since, there is very little documentation about writing and plugging UDFs, any help would be much appreciated.* Thanks in advance.

1. ran `mvn compile` and `mvn package`
2. copied the `.jar` file into plugins folder under presto (unzipped) directory `/Users/nithin/presto-server-0.166/plugin/udfs/`
3. started coordinator using `bin/launcher run`
   ran `select mysum(10,100)` in Presto CLI, but throws error

Below is error log when I try to run my UDF ('mysum') in Presto CLI. **It is quite evident that Presto is not able to find the UDF, so plugging in wasn't successful. How to fix that? Am I missing any step?**

```
➜  Workspaces ./presto.jar --server localhost:8080 --catalog mysql --schema default --debug
presto:default> select mysum(99,100);
Query 20170228_183509_00002_vr5dt failed: line 1:8: Function mysum not registered
com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.SemanticException: line 1:8: Function mysum not registered
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer$Visitor.visitFunctionCall(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:824)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer$Visitor.visitFunctionCall(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:255)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.FunctionCall.accept(FunctionCall.java:111)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.StackableAstVisitor.process(StackableAstVisitor.java:26)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer$Visitor.process(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:274)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer.analyze(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:231)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.ExpressionAnalyzer.analyzeExpression(ExpressionAnalyzer.java:1406)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer.analyzeExpression(StatementAnalyzer.java:1802)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer.analyzeSelect(StatementAnalyzer.java:1623)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer.visitQuerySpecification(StatementAnalyzer.java:800)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer.visitQuerySpecification(StatementAnalyzer.java:188)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.QuerySpecification.accept(QuerySpecification.java:127)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.AstVisitor.process(AstVisitor.java:27)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer.visitQuery(StatementAnalyzer.java:550)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer.visitQuery(StatementAnalyzer.java:188)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.Query.accept(Query.java:94)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.AstVisitor.process(AstVisitor.java:27)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:68)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:60)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryExecution.doAnalyzeQuery(SqlQueryExecution.java:290)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryExecution.analyzeQuery(SqlQueryExecution.java:276)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryExecution.start(SqlQueryExecution.java:234)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.QueuedExecution.lambda$start$1(QueuedExecution.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
select mysum(99,100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your connector plugin should provide the list of UDF classes. See [Plugin#getFunctions](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-spi/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/spi/Plugin.java#L52-L55)

```
default Set<Class<?>> getFunctions()
{
    return emptySet();
}
```

Please override the method and expose classes of UDF classes.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually prefer is to build the presto UDF jar locally and try to install on dockerized presto cluster to make sure, it gets installed successfully.

I have used gradle to build my jar and used the latest modules after presto foundation launch as dependencies. While in maven, the file in meta-inf/services is automatically created, In gradle i had to set it up manually.

Here is the [github](https://github.com/anilkulkarni87/prestoudf) repo and steps to test the UDF locally.